# C++ syntax highlighting html generator

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm writing blog posts for my company blog and I would like code snippets to show up with syntax highlighting.

All I can do is write html/css.

Is there any app/webapp that will let me paste in a c++ code snippet and get a chunk of html with the highlighting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this [Online syntax highlighting Site](http://tohtml.com), and especially [the C++ section](http://tohtml.com/cpp).

You paste in your code and it does the hard work.

Comment: Note - this tool will not work for code segments longer than 1000 characters, so is not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

I use emacs <kbd>M-X</kbd>htmlize-buffer<kbd>RET</kbd>. Also [enscript](http://www.markkurossi.com/genscript/) is very powerful to generate colorized HTML from many source code formats.

Answer (score 1):

For others looking for a solution to this problem - you should checkout:

http://oneqonea.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-do-i-add-syntax-highlighting-to-my.html

It's a really easy "SyntaxHighlighter for Blogger" tutorial with screenshots and everything.

You should be up and running in only a few minutes.

Also, for your C++ application, make sure you have the shBrushCpp.js library referenced in your <head></head> section like this:

```
<head>
    <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCpp.js' type='text/javascript'/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.syntaxhighlight.com - supporting 222 languages. Paste your code and get the formatted html.

Comment: The link you provided has expired.

Comment: Yes, like @mtb said, the link has expired.